# Propagate viewModel in run time created component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm facing a problem, I have a list with a viewModel, a store inside the view model. List item is in another js file, no view model for it, if in my list view I have this item already declared then it's ok, it retrieve the list vm, but if I add one list item by code in the listController then it doesn't retrieve the vm and crash saying Cannot use bind config without a viewModel

Here's a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25be

Regards.

Comment: That is really weird way to be using a list. Why aren't you just using a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the parent key. The following code should work:

```
var item = Ext.create({ 
        xtype: 'victimeitem',
        viewModel: {
            parent: vm
        }
    });
```